# Euler's infinite expressions for $\frac{\pi^2}6$

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, pi, infinite-product

Euler's famous expression for $\frac{\pi^2}6=\sum\frac1{n^2}$ is very elegant.
I have also seen a second expression
$$\frac{\pi^2}6=\prod_p\frac{p^2}{p^2-1}$$
that seems [attributed](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~huberty/math5337/groupe/expresspi.html) to Euler too (the product is taken over all primes $p$). It is said that these two expressions are effectively equivalent.

I do note that the [Wallis product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product) seems to use Euler's infinite product for the sine function to obtain a value for $\frac\pi2$ and I suspect a similar approach could be used to obtain my second expression, though I cannot see how at present. Can anybody explain (or provide a link to an explanation of) how my product expression is derived and if it can be attributed to Euler (or obtained from his work)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_product

Comment: Do you want to know how $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}=\prod\frac{p^2}{p^2-1}$?

Comment: Direct consequence of the expansion $\frac1{1-x}=\sum\limits_{n\geqslant0}x^n$ applied to each $x=\frac1{p^2}$. Likewise, for every $i>1$, $$\prod_p\frac{p^i}{p^i-1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^i}(=\zeta(i))$$

Comment: Thanks everyone for directing me to the Euler product and the zeta function. I found a link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_the_Euler_product_formula_for_the_Riemann_zeta_function) that shows a couple of proofs. For me it is interesting to see how, in Euler's original proof, sieving provides a wonderfully intuitive way to arrive at the infinite product over all primes.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
\prod_{p\in\mathbb{P}}\frac{p^\alpha}{p^\alpha-1}
&=\prod_{p\in\mathbb{P}}\frac1{1-\frac1{p^\alpha}}\\
&=\prod_{p\in\mathbb{P}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{p^{k\alpha}}\tag1
\end{align}
$$
Applying the [Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic), for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there is a unique product
$$
n^\alpha=\prod_{j=1}^\infty p_j^{k_j\alpha}\tag2
$$
where only finitely many $k_j\ne0$. Thus, there is exactly one product of terms in $(1)$ corresponding to $n$. For example,
$$
\color{#CCC}{\cdots+\frac1{11^\alpha}+}\frac1{12^\alpha}\color{#CCC}{+\frac1{13^\alpha}+\cdots}
$$
corresponds to the term in the product
$$
\color{#CCC}{\left(1+2^\alpha+\color{#000}{2^{2\alpha}}+\cdots\right)\left(1+\color{#000}{3^\alpha}+3^{2\alpha}+\cdots\right)\left(\color{#000}{1}+5^\alpha+5^{2\alpha}+\cdots\right)\cdots}
$$
Therefore, adding up all the products of terms in $(1)$, we get
$$
\prod_{p\in\mathbb{P}}\frac{p^\alpha}{p^\alpha-1}
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^\alpha}\tag3
$$

Comment: Thanks robjohn. I am looking through your response. I have been looking at [geometric series documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Geometric_series)  but I can't find how you derived the sum at (1). Please could you add a link. Thanks

Comment: The basic geometric series $$\frac1{1-r}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty r^k$$ where $r=\frac1{p^\alpha}$.